# What's the theorem used in the equality?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

$\frac {\partial u} {\partial t}(x,y,t)=\Delta u(x,y,t), (x,y) \in \Omega, t>0 $

$\nu \cdot \nabla u(x,y,t)=0 , (x,y) \in \partial \Omega, t>0$

$u(x,y,0)=f(x,y)$

In the proof of showing $u^2(x,y,t)$ decreases with time, what is the theorem used for the following equality.

$\int _\Omega u\Delta u dxdy = \int _{\partial \Omega} u(\nu \nabla u)ds - \int _\Omega \lvert \nabla u \rvert ^2 dxdy$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... what is the theorem used for the following equality. $$\int _\Omega u\Delta u\, dx\, dy = \int _{\partial \Omega} u(\nu \nabla u)ds - \int _\Omega \lvert \nabla u \rvert ^2\, dx\, dy$$

Actually the equation should be

$$\int_\Omega u\Delta u\, dx\, dy = \int_{\partial \Omega} u\nabla u \cdot \nu\, ds - \int_\Omega \lvert \nabla u\rvert^2\, dx\, dy.$$

This is a consequence of the divergence theorem. First

$$ \int_{\partial \Omega} u\nabla u\cdot \nu \, ds = \int_\Omega \operatorname{div}{(u\nabla u)} \, dx\, dy.\tag{1} $$

Since

$$\operatorname{div}{(u\nabla u)} = u\operatorname{div}{(\nabla u)} + \nabla u\cdot \nabla u = u\Delta u + |\nabla u|^2,$$

then

$$ \int_\Omega \operatorname{div}{(u\nabla u)}\, dx\, dy = \int_\Omega u\Delta u\, dx\, dy + \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2\, dx\, dy.\tag{2} $$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have

$$\int_{\partial \Omega} u\nabla u\cdot \nu\, ds = \int_\Omega u\Delta u\, dx\, dy + \int_\Omega \lvert \nabla u\rvert^2\, dx\, dy$$

or

$$\int_\Omega u\Delta u\, dx\, dy = \int_{\partial \Omega} u\nabla u\cdot \nu\, ds - \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2\, dx\, dy.$$